# Building technique for modelling Thomas the Tank Engine faces

Tags: building, trains

I'm building [Thomas the Tank Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Tank_Engine) trains, and I'm looking for techniques to build realistic faces. I'd like the trains be able to run on standard LEGO rails, so I'm targeting 8-wide engines. This series has been visualized a number of different ways over the years. In terms of style, I'd prefer to stick as close as possible to the live action models:

[image: Thomas photo]

This leads me to the following requirements:

- Faces must be no more than 6 wide
- No stickers or non-LEGO elements
- Faces should enhance the recognizably of these models as Thomas trains
- Faces should generally be cute from a child's point of view

There have been many attempts to create Thomas models at LEGO scale. Here's [one of the best examples](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legocityson/49941111908/in/photostream/) that I've seen:

[image: Example face]

That's a larger scale than I need, but hopefully it helps provide context. I've tried emulating these techniques at smaller scale using 1x1 round eye pieces, and my attempts look a bit off. What approaches could be used to create appropriate faces at this scale?

Comment: slightly tongue in cheek, but still to the point : [Duplo, Train Thomas & Friends Face, Thomas Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52053pb01) ;)

Comment: The problem is, with 6 wide to play with, and 2 of those taken up by 1×1 eyes, you're left with either 0 or 2 for the nose - and you need a nose.  So 5 wide might be better, but I don't think you can make a very good circle in 5, and a centred mouth is then 1 or 3 unless you can squeeze in an offset without adding too much depth

Comment: [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/search/?show_printed=on&include_accessory=1&include_gear=1&q=thomas+engine&search_type=all) has a few Thomas tank engine MOCs that might help out.